# Java Beginner: Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java

I've been scouring the java textbook for hours trying to determine what I'm doing wrong. The error I'm getting back is "Cannot find symbol" on line 13, which is the line with the code:

```
 System.out.println("The three initials are " + 
     getInitials(Harry, Joseph, Hacker));
```

The instructions are commented in the code. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the names I've set up.. But I'm not sure.

```
public class InitialsTest {
     /**
       Gets the initials of this name
      @params first, middle, and last names
      @return a string consisting of the first character of the first, middle,
  and last name
      */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("The three initials are " + 
         getInitials(Harry, Joseph, Hacker));
    }

    public static String getInitials(String one, String two, String three) {
        String initials = one.substring(0,1) + two.substring(0,1) + three.substring(0,1);
        return initials;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 16):

```
System.out.println("The three initials are " 
    + getInitials("Harry", "Joseph", "Hacker")); //Enclosed within double quotes
```

This is how you pass `String` literals.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println("The three initials are " + 
     getInitials("Harry", "Joseph", "Hacker"));
```

just use the double quotes .
if you would have declared them as variables in your code then double quotes are not needed ,

Answer (score 3):

You should pass it this way:

```
System.out.println("The three initials are " 
    + getInitials("Harry", "Joseph", "Hacker"));
```

`Harry, Joseph, Hacker` without double quotes ( " " ) are variable and you get error because you didn't declare any variable with those names.

NOTE : ALL string in Java **must** be enclosed in **double quotes**.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 string values passed to `getInitials()`, string literals has to be enclosed with in `"`

```
System.out.println("The three initials are " + 
          getInitials("Harry", "Joseph", "Hacker"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings have to be always within " and ". So your code would be

```
System.out.println("The three initials are " + 
 getInitials("Harry", "Joseph", "Hacker"));
```

Also, you could also use

```
String initials = one.charAt(0)+two.charAt(0)+three.charAt(0);
```

within your getInitials() function instead of

```
String initials = one.substring(0,1) + two.substring(0,1) + three.substring(0,1);
```

Just saying. Both get you the character at the 0th index position in the String, but charAt returns as a Character rather than as a String.

Comment: Shouldn't the charAt function use () instead of []? Like one.charAt(0) + two.charAt(0) + three.charAt(0)

Comment: yeah sorry my bad :)